# App crashes after I run the script

Tags: ios, user-interface, automation

I'm trying to run my tests scripts on different device(iPhone, iPad, Air), but all the same. When i push Play button ,app started and crashed. And my scripts can not be executed.(Simply stopped). Please tell me why!?I use UI automation tool.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main.m in main function use this code,

```
@try {
        @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RRAppDelegate class]));
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog( @"There is some error === %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",exception]);
    }
```

It will show u the err reason. I haven't 50 reputation, so i am unable to comment.

Comment: This code is bad. The proper way is to set an exception breakpoint in Xcode instead of using this code!